# Stack overflow when running Rust code with too much include_bytes!(...) in debug mode

Tags: rust, stack-overflow

I have a moderately-sized Rust project which compiles warning-free succesfully and runs successfully with `cargo run --release`. However, `cargo run` fails with `` error: process didn't exit successfully: `target\\debug\\blah.exe` (exit code: 0xc00000fd, STATUS_STACK_OVERFLOW) ``.

I was able to track the problem to the place where I do `include_bytes!(...)` for eight different files; a couple of them are larger than others (around 340 Kb; the rest is about 130, 90, 75, 50, 45, and 10). Removing the load for any of two larger files (and only for those two) stops `cargo run` from crashing. Just in case I have tried to use `static` instead of local `let` -- with the same result, `cargo run` crashes with stack overflow, `cargo run --release` does not. I have the same result both for stable-x86_64-pc-windows-msvc and nightly-x86_64-pc-windows-msvc. Stable is default, `rustc --version` reports 1.73.0. I would like to be able to do `cargo run` without crashing.

The following code illustrates the problem:

```
use sdl2::mixer::Chunk;
fn main() {
    let tmp1 = *include_bytes!("test.wav");
    let tmp2 = *include_bytes!("test.wav");
    let tmp3 = *include_bytes!("test.wav");

    let chunk1 = Chunk::from_raw_buffer(Box::new(tmp1));
    let chunk2 = Chunk::from_raw_buffer(Box::new(tmp2));
    let chunk3 = Chunk::from_raw_buffer(Box::new(tmp3));
}
```

where `test.wav` is an appropriately big file located next to `main.rs`.

Comment: And where the difference with `--release` comes from?

Comment: It's differently optimized, thus it might not be quite as pressed for stack space.

Comment: This is more or less expected. Don't dereference `include_bytes`. There's no point in copying so much data to the stack.

Comment: @drewtato I think I need to dereference it: https://docs.rs/sdl2/latest/sdl2/mixer/struct.Chunk.html#method.from_raw_buffer Am I wrong? I know a thing or two about low-level stuff, but I am very new to Rust.

Comment: [`Box<[T]>` implements `From<&[T]>`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/primitive.slice.html#impl-From%3C%26%5BT%5D%3E-for-Box%3C%5BT%5D%3E) so you should be able to do just `Chunk::from_raw_buffer (include_bytes!("test.wav").into())`

Comment: @Jmb it does not work: "the trait From<&[u8; 346080]> is not implemented for Box<[_]>"

Comment: Yes it should be `&include_bytes!("test.wav")[..].into()` or `include_bytes!("test.wav").as_slice().into()`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The core problem is that in Rust, arrays implement `Copy` and by dereferencing the array reference produced by `include_bytes!` you directly put a copy of the array onto the stack.

In release builds putting the array onto the stack and subsequently creating a boxed slice from it is very likely optimized away to directly create the box from the reference, but that optimization is usually missed in debug builds.

Instead, if the method you want to call expects a `Box<[T]>` you should just directly convert the array reference that `include_bytes!` produces into a boxed slice:

```rust
let tmp1: Box<[u8]> = include_bytes!("test.wav")[..].into();
```

That way you avoid allocating a needlessly large array on the stack.